# NSUserDefaults - Saving UIImageView Position

Tags: ios, uiimageview, loading, nsuserdefaults

In my application, I have a UIImageView and a UIButton. The UIImageView has a UIPanGestureRecognizer, and can be dragged around the screen. I have written:

`int defaultBallLocation = ball.center;`
in my `- (IBAction)saveButton`

and Xcode is saying "Cannot associate CGPoint with int".

So, how can I save the ball (UIImageView) position on the screen by pressing "save", then load the saved position by pressing "load" through NSUserDefaults? I have worked with NSUserDefaults before, but only with a UISegmentedController. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another option, you can store it as string:

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// Set
[userDefaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(yourPoint) forKey:@"pointPosition"];
// Save
[userDefaults synchronize];
// Get
CGPoint thePoint = CGPointFromString([userDefaults objectForKey:@"pointPosition"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an `int` with a `CGPoint` struct which is not possible.

To save it into `NSUserDefaults` you could do:

```
CGFloat x = ball.center.x;
CGFloat y = ball.center.y;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setFloat:x forKey:@"x"];
[defaults setFloat:y forKey:@"y"];
```

Comment: This answer is correct but just for more information, you can access each point as an int by doing int defaultBallLocationXCoord = ball.center.x (or ball.center.y)

Comment: Thank you but how would I load this?

Comment: @Chase Have you read the API documentation of `NSUserDefaults`? You wrote that you have worked with `NSUserDefaults` previously so then you should know how to load something from it. If not then this is a good practice for you.

Comment: Yes but I've only loaded integers, not CGPoints.

Comment: @PeterWarbo This solution won't work because you can't store `NSValue` objects in `NSUserDefaults`. It's not listed as a valid object in the docs for `NSUserDefaults` and I just tried it to confirm and sure enough it results in an error in the console and the value is ignored. The proper solution is to store the two values of the `CGPoint` using two different keys.

Comment: @rmaddy you are correct, thanks. I forgot about how "picky" `NSUserDefaults` is. I've updated my answer.